# mqtt json data printing

Tags: python, json, mqtt

Trying to print out a single temperature value when I receive a MQTT message. Whats happening at the moment is that only the full MQTT message is printed but not the value. "Test" is also not printed.

Code:

```
import context
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
import json

def on_message(mqttc, obj, msg):
    print(msg.payload)
    stuff = json_dumps(str(msg.payload))
    print(msg.payload['HTU21']['Temperature'])
    print ("Test")
```

Output:

```
{"Time":"2018-12-15T03:02:34","HTU21":{"Temperature":18.8,"Humidity":71.2},"TempUnit":"C"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's stopping because it's throwing an error (and the MQTT library is catching and hiding the error) when you try to access fields in the `msg.payload` (which is still a string).

If you use the `stuff` json object then it should work.

```
def on_message(mqttc, obj, msg):
    print(msg.payload)
    stuff = json_dumps(str(msg.payload))
    print(stuff['HTU21']['Temperature'])
    print ("Test")
```